# jQuery plugin to have Facebook styled search box with image thumbnails?

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook

I will work on a search box with inspiration from Facebook where image thumbnails would be displayed besides the auto-suggested matches.

This is the goal : [link to sample image](http://i40.tinypic.com/sgljqd.jpg)

I wonder if there is any jQuery plugin that would just do this. I tried to search for a one but unable to find.

If there is no plugin for this task, I'd like to know the basic plugins needed to implemented such an auto-suggest/image thumbnail display combination.

Any suggestion and hint is welcomed. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See following demo
http://demos.9lessons.info/auto.htm
and article
http://www.9lessons.info/2009/06/autosuggestion-with-jquery-ajax-and-php.html